# How to return an array from a function by value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I know it is inefficient to return an array by value instead of with a pointer. However, my CS class final has a requirement that a function is to return a 5 digit 1D array as a value. As such, I can not return the array by pointer. I am also unable to have any global variables.

I have tried

```
float FunctionName(){
float myVar[5];
//process data
return myVar;
}
```

I have also tried

```
float[] FunctionName(){
float myVar[5];
//process data
return myVar;
}
```

I even tried tricking the compiler with

```
float FunctionName(float myVar[5]) {
     //process data
     return myVar;
 }
```

I have read that it is impossible, but I am guessing it is just really weird or hard to do. I think it might be possible with an enum type, but I am unsure how I would set that up.

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: This question demonstrated more research than the dup, but the dup offers fairly comprehensive answers.

Comment: @jxh I actually found the duplicate, but the answers all said that it was impossible, and to just use pointers. I guess the 2 are similar enough though.

Comment: You sometimes have to read beyond the accepted answer to find the right answer. In this case, look at the second most popular answer in the dup.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return an array by value. However, you can do that with an `std::array`, which is a wrapper around an array:

```
#include <array>

std::array<float, 5> FunctionName() {
    std::array<float, 5> data;
    //process data
    return data;
}
```

Comment: That actually works thanks. Is there any documentation for that specific array type? I haven't seen that before, but it already looks useful.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 0):

> You can return the pointer to array in C style doing:

```
float* FunctionName(){
float myVar[5];

float* p = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * 5);
//process data

return p;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `std::unique_ptr` if you want to dynamically create the array.

Comment: Yes, I just supposed he wanted a fixed  one of 5 elements as he said in the post

Comment: Perhaps, but your code uses `malloc`, which is dynamic. And the caller has to remember to use `free`, in a C++ program.

Comment: Right. I should improve my use of smart pointers ;)

Comment: https://tio.run/##jU69DoIwEN55iosOlBATFxaoPIYLEtOUai7aFkubQIzPjgcdjE7eDZd8P/d9su93VynnLRp5D50CrpW2bqqTD4J28E4JXc8ieAuXYIBl8EyAZkX0dBQODjD4riy1uKlzMPgIiqPxTVuzIqtW8cU6YIQBknhf0eFQVJDnmMUfDbbEYFQ75YMzkaiS17wYtcDf8JEcVIn9kbH2kzZ44Bw2tHRGyozOLzY9mXQJfQM